# Fingerprint SDK 3.1.1

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I have problems with this error my fingerprint reader is digital persona and when I click the register button the popup error was:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Fprint.exe
>
> Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set

I don't know what are the meaning of this error.

How can I solve this problem?

And what is this `YourSecretKey`?  This is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8gnlpK9_Os) of the tutorial for the fingerprint and when they execute the program it runs correctly.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        fpreg = New FlexCodeSDK.FinFPReg
        fpreg.AddDeviceInfo("C700F001339", "7901D3C13E34109", "VPFAAB943C33362467D451A0")

        fpreg.FPRegistrationStart("YourSecretKey")


    End Sub

Comment: sorry i cant post the picture of the code all i can do is to write it . that's the code iv'e work for now but when i debug it the error is  the fpreg.FPregistration("YourSecretKey") .

Comment: Your secret key is the secret key for your device, I imagine.  This may be why you're getting your error.  Have you contacted the manufacturer about this?